# Qt - QTest::keyClick() - is it synchronized to paint?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have a GUI which I want to test with `QTest`.

I'm planning on having a separate thread which executes [QTest::keyClick()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtest.html#keyClick) test steps but I want to synchronize my test steps with `QWidget::repaint()` i.e. I want each `QTest::keyClick()` to happen only after the repaint (if any) caused by the repaint from the previous `QTest::keyClick()`

1. `QTest::keyClick()`
2. Repaint from step 1
3. `QTest::keyClick()`
4. Repaint from step 2

I do not want

1. `QTest::keyClick()`
2. `QTest::keyClick()`
3. Repaint from step 1
4. Repaint from step 2

**QUESTION**
How to make sure `keyClick()`s do not occur before paint event from previous `keyClick()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for synchronization: each call to `keyClick()` results in a call to `qApp->processEvents()`

```
static void simulateEvent(QWindow *window, bool press, int code,
                              Qt::KeyboardModifiers modifier, QString text, bool repeat, int delay=-1)
    {
        QEvent::Type type;
        type = press ? QEvent::KeyPress : QEvent::KeyRelease;
        qt_handleKeyEvent(window, type, code, modifier, text, repeat, delay);
        qApp->processEvents();
    }
```

which would trigger any paint events before the next `QTest.keyClick()`.